# Longer Insertion and Read time for records in orientdb using .NET binary

Tags: c#, .net, orientdb, graph-databases, orientdb-2.1

I am using following queries to insert into the database from .NET binary and it takes close to **5 hours** to load the orientdb community version with just **12000 vertex and 57000 Edges**.

### The following are the queries:

1)

```
     .Update()
     .Class("abc")
     .Set("name", xyz)
     .Upsert()
     .Where("name")
     .Equals(xyz)
     .Run();
```

2)

```
Update Account SET From_Date = ?, To_Date = ?, out = (select from Firm where name = ?), in = (select from Contact where LastName = ? and FirstName = ?) UPSERT WHERE out = (select from Firm where name = ?) and in = (select from Contact where LastName = ? and FirstName = ?)
```

---

I am using the 2) query twice in the code with parameters passed through array of strings and 1) is used once. The queries are run sequentially one after the other.

**I am using Orientdb 2.2.3 version with OrientDB-Net.binary.Innov8tive.0.1.5 package**

**Is there any configuration in the code or in the orientdb server xml that I could make to make the read and inserts quick?**

Could you guys please help me out.
Thanks!

Comment: Which is the edge class here?

Comment: Account is the edge class in the 2) query

Comment: Why do you Upsert on the Edge class?
You should use create edge statement  

http://orientdb.com/docs/2.2/SQL-Create-Edge.html

Comment: I am doing to upsert as the code runs every week. wont creating create a duplicate issue for the edges?

Comment: With this Upsert you will not create a proper graph. You will not be able to 
traverse relationship in this way.

Comment: Then what should the query be in order to create a proper graph?

Comment: http://orientdb.com/docs/2.2/SQL-Create-Edge.html

OrientDB stores pointers to edges in the vertices (http://orientdb.com/docs/2.2/RidBag.html)
. If you create edges manually that will not happen.

Comment: BTW if you want to speed up vertex edge creation you should use Batch sql
http://orientdb.com/docs/2.2/SQL-batch.html

Comment: Well the update is required if there are changes in the same edge the next time a batch job is run then instead of updating the same edge it would create a new edge and with part same and part new information. And I think vertex creation is not an issue its the edges that are taking time due to lot of select sub queries.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116004/discussion-between-howard-roark-and-wolf4ood).